# "Select statement includes a reserved word" issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub txtGroupSearch_Enter()
    cmbGroups.RowSource = "Select GroupName, GroupNum, from tblGroupHeader Where GroupName like '*" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' or GroupNum like '*" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
End Sub
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: `Select GroupName, GroupNum, from` comma before `from`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma after GroupNum changes the statement such that it thinks 'from' will be a column name

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something dumb! Side question: My like operator will  show records with search text inside them like if i search "H" something like "Pieter21's House" might populate the cmbGoups box. do you know how  I only get it to search the start of a word?

Answer (score 1):

For the second question on the 'like' statement:

Remove the first * in:

```
like '*" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*'
```

Then with txtgroupSearch.Value = 'H' it will look for anything matching 'H*' which means starting with 'H'.